# Calling c++ grpc .so file(library) function from NodeJS gives ASSERTION FAILED: insert_result.second error why?

Tags: c++, node.js, grpc

I am developing a nodejs which tries to call functions from c++ .so file. I am successfully calling functions from c++ .so file but when i try to call connect function which is grpc client and uses channel->GetState(true) function it gives:

```
E1129 11:15:16 553088 grpc_ares_ev_driver_posix.cc:119] ASSERTION FAILED: insert_result.second
```

error. I can't debug it because it is built code. Is there anyone know why it is giving such kind of error.

I tried same scenario like tried to call c++ .so file functions from c# and tried to use connect function which uses channel->GetState(true) function. It connects to the server and not giving error.